# nginx: server_name regex and wildcard server_name at the same time

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a trouble with nginx config for site. 

First config use **wildcard server_name**:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name _;
     return 444;
server_name *.domain.tld;
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

And the second use **regex** the server_name to reverse proxy:

```
server {
     listen      80;
     listen      [::]:80;
     server_name    ~^www(?<port>\d{4,5}+)\.sub\.domain\.tld$;
     location / {
            proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:$port;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  Host $host;
     }
}
```

But when i connect to site http://www11111.sub.domain.tld, server **return 444** . Seem like nginx  use config 1 for this request. 
Where am i wrong ?, Can you explain or resolve?
Sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Your wildcard server name will always take priority over your regex server name. You can try this config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name "~^www(?<port>\d{4,5}+)\.sub\.domain\.com$";
    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:$port;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    # using negative regex assertion with the server_name directive
    server_name "~^(?!www\d{4,5}\.\sub\.).*\.domain\.com$";
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    # catch all other host names
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

If you want to process `domain.com` hostname like the others, you can replace `server_name "~^(?!www\d{4,5}\.\sub\.).*\.domain\.com$";` with the `server_name "~^(?!www\d{4,5}\.\sub\.)(?:.*\.)?domain\.com$";`.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, I will try this at weekend, I have just use a lua-redis for this & extended to hide port in server_name.
Your explanation is very concise.